# easy responsive tab jquery plugin works differently

Tags: jquery

I just used Easy Responsive Tabs Plugin for tabs but when i click any tab it overwrites my url with its hash which i dont want on my url.initially it was like 'http://www.boomracingrc.com/boomrc/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=64187' when i click on any tab then it overwrites the url to something like this 'http://www.boomracingrc.com/boomrc/#horizontalTab2' i dont want it to write anything on my url.Is there any way to do that??If there is any way then it would be very helpful.Any help is appreciated.

my jquery function is

```
     $('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs({
        type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion           
        width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
        fit: true,   // 100% fit in a container
        closed: 'accordion', // Start closed if in accordion view
        activate: function(event) { // Callback function if tab is switched
            alert(window.location.pathname);return false;
            var $tab = $(this);
            var $info = $('#tabInfo');
            var $name = $('span', $info);

            $name.text($tab.text());

            $info.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you need to use that plugin? [jquery ui has easy to use tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) that don't rewrite your url

Comment: I needed the responsive tabs that turns to accordion in mobile so!